# ES6 Class: Global variable is undefined inside of class method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've created an empty array `this.contentElements` as a global var in my class constructor but when I try to push objects to the array from one of my methods I get the error `'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'`. I can't get my head around why this isn't working.

When I log the array inside of the constructor it returns the empty array but when I try to log it inside my method it returns undefined.

I've tried binding the method as well using arrow function expression, with 0 success.

```
export class Intro {

 constructor() {
    this.createTimeline();
    this.contentElements = []; 
 }

  createTimeline() {
    const contentArray = Array.from(document.querySelector('.intro-overlay').querySelectorAll('.content'));  

   contentArray.map(content => {
     const contentEl = content;
     const contentBounds = contentEl.getBoundingClientRect();
     const contentTop = contentBounds.top;

     this.contentElements.push({
       el: contentEl,
       top: contentTop
     })

     console.log(this.contentElements)
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `createTimeline` before `this.contentElements` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, you need to assign the empty array to this.contentElements before invoking this.createTimeline().

Answer (score 0):

change the order in your constructor

contentElements needs to initialized first before being used

```
export class Intro {

 constructor() {
    this.contentElements = [];
    this.createTimeline();
 }

  createTimeline() {
    const contentArray = Array.from(document.querySelector('.intro- 
    overlay').querySelectorAll('.content'));  

   contentArray.map(content => {
     const contentEl = content;
     const contentBounds = contentEl.getBoundingClientRect();
     const contentTop = contentBounds.top;

     this.contentElements.push({
       el: contentEl,
       top: contentTop
     })

     console.log(this.contentElements)
   });
  }
}
```